# Spread Operator for Function calls

Tags: javascript

```js
function timed(f) {
  return function(...args) { // Collect args into a rest parameter array
    console.log(`entring function ${f.name}`);
    let startTime = Date.now();
    try {
      return f(...args); // Spread the args back out again
    } finally {
      console.log(`exting ${f.name} after ${Date.now()-startTime}ms`);
    }
  };
}

function benchmark(n) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; ++i) sum += i;
  return sum;
}

timed(benchmark)(1000000);
```

JavaScript: Definitive Guide p. 196: Calling `f(args)` works on the example. Why author use f`(...args)` instead of `f(args)`?

For safety?

Comment: `timed` is a function. It takes one argument (`f`, which is a function) and returns an anonymous function. The anonymous function (that is being returned) takes the arguments-list as an array `args`. And, it returns the result of calling `f` (ie, the original function sent as argument to `timed`) with the arguments `args`. Consider reading about [`Closures, Currying`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/playing-around-with-closures-currying-and-cool-abstractions/)

Comment: `f(args)` calls `f` with all of the arguments in an array as the first argument. `f(...args)` calls `f` with th same args that `timed(benchmark)` was called with.

Comment: "*calling f(args) works on the example*" - yes, but it wouldn't work if  `benchmark` had multiple parameters. Just because it works on one example is not a good reason to assume it works always.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not spread the arguments - if you do `return f(args);` - then you'll be passing an array to the function.

This *just so happens* to work in this example because `benchmark` will coerce the array (`n`) when doing the `i <= n` comparison - for example, `2 < [1000000]` is valid code and happens to produce the logic you want - but it's very confusing.

Better to spread the arguments so that the function pased into `timed` gets the original arguments, whatever they may be, rather than always a single array as the only argument. Spreading will mean that

```
timed(benchmark)(1000000);
```

results in

```
benchmark(1000000)
```

Not spreading will mean that the above results in

```
benchmark([1000000])
```

Comment: "*you'll be passing an array to the function*" - ah, I had assumed the OP meant when they were not using spread syntax for the call they wouldn't use a rest parameter in the returned function either